# Live colour changing

Tags: javascript, php

I have made a color changer. but now I want to add a form to it. 
if you change the dropdown it must show the color change directly. 
what is the best way to do this?

Below I have added my code for the color changer

```
 $im = b.gif;
    $index = imagecolorclosest ( $im,  128,128,128); // old color
    imagecolorset($im,$index,$color[0],$color[1],$color[2]); // new color

    $imgname = "result.gif";
    imagegif($im, $imgname ); // save image as gif
    imagedestroy($im);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use `<input type="color" />`, you could use 3 `<input type="range">` add change listeners to them and update the style of element you wish whenever one of them is changed. (The event `change` will trigger after you release the input, the event `input` will trigger whenever the value is changed, even if you are still holding the input). I made the coloring gets and sets using `Object.defineProperty` to make it easier to test.

```js
["red", "green", "blue", "opacity"].forEach(function(colorType) {
  Object.defineProperty(this, colorType, {
    get: function() {
      return +document.querySelector("#" + colorType).value;
    }
  });
  document.querySelector("#" + colorType).addEventListener("input", onChange);
});

Object.defineProperty(this, "result", {
  set: function(newColor) {
    document.querySelector("#result").setAttribute("style", "background-color: rgba(" + newColor + ");");
  }
});

onChange();

function onChange() {
  result = [red, green, blue, opacity].join(", ");
}
```

```css
#result {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<form id="result">
  <input type="range" id="red" name="red" min="0" max="255" />
  <input type="range" id="green" name="green" min="0" max="255" />
  <input type="range" id="blue" name="blue" min="0" max="255" />
  <input type="range" id="opacity" name="opacity" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" />
</form>
```

```js
Object.defineProperty(this, "color", {
  get: function() {
    return document.querySelector("#color").value;
  }
});
document.querySelector("#color").addEventListener("input", onChange);

Object.defineProperty(this, "result", {
  set: function(newColor) {
    document.querySelector("#result").setAttribute("style", "background-color: " + newColor + ";");
  }
});

onChange();

function onChange() {
  result = color;
}
```

```css
#result {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<form id="result">
  <input type="color" id="color" name="color" />
</form>
```

Comment: Waauw thanks, i will true to fix the code with the last one... i make a 'plugin' for a balloon bow. or a pillar.  thanks a lot !!!

Comment: If my answer helped you, you can accept it by clicking on the grey/green check next to it